# Is Alternate Access Mapping scoped to the Web Application?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

On other words, if I wanted to point a sub-domain, like portal.mysite.com, would I do that with AAM or some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using Host Named Site Collections.

From TechNet

> Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 supports both path-based and
>   host-named site collections. The primary difference between path-based
>   and host-named site collections is that all path-based site
>   collections in a Web application share the same host name (DNS name),
>   and each host-named site collection in a Web application is assigned a
>   unique DNS name.
>
> Path-based site collections provide a corporate hosting solution with
>   all site collections sharing the same host name of the Web
>   application. In a path-based deployment, you can have a single site
>   collection at the root of the Web application and additional site
>   collections under managed paths within the Web application.
>
> Host-named site collections provide a scalable Web hosting solution
>   with each site collection assigned to a unique DNS name. In a Web
>   hosting deployment, each host-named site collection has its own vanity
>   host name URL, such as http://customer1.contoso.com,
>   http://customer2.contoso.com, or http://www.customer3.com.
>
> SharePoint Foundation 2010 provides two significant improvements to
>   host-named site collections: the ability to use managed paths with
>   host-named site collections, and the ability to use off-box SSL
>   termination with host-named site collections.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288637.aspx